# Get all possible combinations for a hyphen separated string

Tags: string, python-2.7, list

I have a list of strings which are hyphen separated. Each string can differ in its length.

For example:

```
l = ["a-b-d-e", "f-g", "aa-bb-dd-ee"]
```

I am trying to get all possible combinations for each hyphen separated string and expect for each string a output like this:

**Example for l[0]:**

```
a-b-d-e
a-bde
a-bd-e
ab-de
abd-e
abde
```

**Example for l[1]:**

```
f-g
fg
```

** Example for l[2]:**

```
aa-bb-dd-ee
aa-bbddee
aa-bbdd-ee
aabb-ddee
aabbdd-ee
aabbddee
```

I was trying to use `itertools` for this, but wasn't very successful at all. What is the best way to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just use binary arithmetic and you count from 0 to the count of possibilities, the *length-1th* power of 2:

```
def insertHyphens(s, bitset):
    """ The function to set hyphens at the same positions the number bitset has a 1 """
    return "".join(c + '-'*bool(bitset & (1 << i)) for i, c in enumerate(s))

def getCombinations(s):
    """ the generator yielding each possibility """
    lenS = len(s)
    for i in range((1 << lenS) >> 1): #1 << (lenS-1) makes problems with one letter
        yield insertHyphens(s, i)
```

Some use:

```
>>> list(hyphens.getCombinations("abc"))
['abc', 'a-bc', 'ab-c', 'a-b-c']
```

Edit: To use it with '-'-seperated letters/words like in your case, just split it there:

```
>>> list(hyphens.getCombinations("a-b-c-def".split('-')))
['abcdef', 'a-bcdef', 'ab-cdef', 'a-b-cdef', 'abc-def', 'a-bc-def', 'ab-c-def', 'a-b-c-def']
```

Your examples:

```
>>> list(hyphens.getCombinations(l[0].split('-')))
['abcd', 'a-bcd', 'ab-cd', 'a-b-cd', 'abc-d', 'a-bc-d', 'ab-c-d', 'a-b-c-d']
>>> list(hyphens.getCombinations(l[1].split('-')))
['fg', 'f-g']
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. But the output generated is not what I expected, it is: a-b-c-df-g and a-b-c-d-f-g.

Comment: You must input an element of ``l`` into the function and not the whole list. You see that when you pass a list as a parameter, the elements keep being one and the gaps between the elements are changed.

Comment: Thank you Sir! You saved my day!